# using templates in primefaces JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

I have main page index.xhtml with declared place to put content dependent on page clicked.

```
            <br>
            <div id="centerContent">
        <ui:insert name="centerContent" >
              <ui:param name="mainTag" value="" />
        <ui:include src="/template/commonContent.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
                <h4>#{mainTag}</h4>
           </div>
            </br><br></br>
            <p:panel id="content">
                        <h:form>
    <h:inputText id="namez" ></h:inputText>
</h:form>
            </p:panel>       
        </p:layoutUnit>
```

my template commonContent is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >
    <body>
        <ui:composition>
        <h1>Ubezpieczamy najlepiej!</h1>
        </ui:composition>
    </body>
</html>
```

and page for sending emails is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >
    <h:body>

        <ui:composition template="index.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="centerContent">
                <h2>Zapytaj</h2>
                        <h:commandButton actionListener="#{mySendBean.sendMail2()}" value="Welcome Me">
            </h:commandButton>
                        <ui:param name="mainTag" value="Z chęcią odpowiemy" />
            </ui:define>


        </ui:composition>

    </h:body>
```

when commandButton is put on main pages it works, email is sent, but when loaded via template it didn't work. All things work but not `<h:commandButton actionListener="#{mySendBean.sendMail2()}" value="Welcome Me">`. **Why it doesn't work when loaded via clicked template**?

bean code:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.mail.*;
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.Email;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;


/**
 *
 * @author root
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class mySendBean {

    private myEmailSend mE;
    /**
     * Creates a new instance of mySendBean
     */
    public mySendBean() {
        mE=new myEmailSend();
    }

    private static int j;

    /**
     * Get the value of j
     *
     * @return the value of j
     */
    public int getJ() {
        return j;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of j
     *
     * @param j new value of j
     */
    public void setJ(int j) {
        this.j = j;
    }

        private String name="iop";

    /**
     * Get the value of name
     *
     * @return the value of name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of name
     *
     * @param name new value of name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        sendMail2();
    }

    public String getSayWelcome(){
       //check if null?
       if("".equals(name) || name ==null){
        return "";
       }else{
        return "Ajax message : Welcome " + name;
       }
    }

    public void setSendMail(){
        sendMail2();
    }
    public void sendMail2(){ 
        j=getJ();
        setJ(++j);

        Email email = new SimpleEmail();
        try {
        //send mail
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had to include content in `<h:form>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      >
    <h:body>

        <ui:composition template="index.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="centerContent">
                    <h:form>
                        <ui:param name="mainTag" value="Z chęcią odpowiemy" />
                <h2>Zapytaj</h2>
                        <h4>#{mainTag}</h4>
                        <h:commandButton actionListener="#{mySendBean.sendMail2()}" value="Welcome Me">
            </h:commandButton>
                    </h:form>
            </ui:define>


        </ui:composition>

    </h:body>

</html>
```